# Unable to see Pivot4J View in Pentaho Business Analytics User console

Tags: pentaho, pivot4j

I have installed biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386 and pivot4J 0.9 versions. I am able to loginto the console but when I click File->New am not able to see Pivot4J view. Please let me know what needs to be done to fix this problem.

Screenshot of the user console is attahced.

Regards,
Dexter.

[image: Unable to see Pivot4J view]

Comment: What does the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386 and pivot4J 0.9 versions was creating the problem. So uninstalled biserver6.0 and installed biserver-ce-5.3.0.0-213 along with pivot4J 0.9 and the problem got fixed.

Attached is the snapshot of Pivot4J view in Pentaho business analytics console.
[image]
Dexter.